# Place div between divs in mobile in plain css

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design

I trying to place a div between divs for a mobile screen.

I don't want to use javascript, just plain css. Is there a way to achieve it?

[image]

I'm experimenting with flexboxes order but can't reach my goal.

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.left {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}

.left-1 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  padding: 20px;
}

.left-3 {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
}

.right {
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left-1">1</div>
    <div class="left-3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">2</div>
</section>
```

Comment: You can achieve it using the Grid CSS. You can refer concept  of the grid https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: I had not thought of that, will have a look. thanks @FrontendTeam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve your desired outcome is to use CSS grid layout, which allows for all elements to be siblings, along with a media-query:

```css
/* simple reset to ensure all element sizes are calculated the same way,
   and with the same base-styles: */
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  /* using CSS Grid for layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* setting a gap between adjacent-elements,
     (shorthand for 'row-gap' and 'column-gap') */
  gap: 0.5em;
  /* defining named areas for the contents to be positioned,
     based on rows; the first row comprises of one area named:
     'leftTop' and the second named 'main'; the second row
     has 'leftLower' and 'main'; the reason that 'main' appears
     twice is that we want the element in that position to span
     across both rows: */
  grid-template-areas:
    "leftTop main"
    "leftLower main";
  /* setting height and width to be full-screen: */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  /* setting padding, so that there is a visible gap between the
     elements and the page's borders (obviously, adjust to taste): */
  padding: 0.5em;
}

/* writing the common styles shared by all child-elements into the same
   place for ease of maintenance/updates: */
.parent div {
  padding: 20px;
}

/* the left-1 and left-2 elements will be laid out automatically according
   to their order in the DOM, once any grid-items (the 'left-1', 'left-2',
   and 'right' elements) have been allocated their specific places according
   to the author's design: */
.left-1 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.left-3 {
  background-color: gray;
}

.right {
  background-color: cyan;
  /* here we explicitly place this element into the named (but not quoted)
     main grid-area: */
  grid-area: main;
}

/* when the screen falls below 450px in width (obviously adapt to your own
   requirements): */
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  /* the grid-template-areas are redefined into three single-column rows: */
  .parent {
    grid-template-areas: "topLeft" "main" "lowerLeft";
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="parent">
  <!-- removed the wrapper 'left' column element, in order to allow the
       'right' element to be positioned between the 'left-1' and 'left-3'
       elements when the screen-size changes: -->
  <div class="left-1">1</div>
  <div class="left-3">3</div>
  <div class="right">2</div>
</section>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jp7n8dtb/).

References:

- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family).
- [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).
- [`font-weight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`grid-template-areas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`@media` queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).

Bibliography:

- "[A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)."
- "[Basic Concepts of grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)."
- "[CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)."